React Native Reanimated sharedTransitionTag is not showing animation
I am learning React Native. I followed the documentation of React-Native-Reanimated, but I can't see the animation after using sharedTransitionTag.
I tried to fix the issue by hot reloading, clearing the cache, and restarting the application, but none of the tricks worked.
App.js
import * as React from 'react';
import { View, Button } from 'react-native';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import Animated from 'react-native-reanimated';

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

function Screen1({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <Animated.View
        style={{ width: 150, height: 150, backgroundColor: 'green' }}
        sharedTransitionTag="sharedTag"
      />
      <Button title="Screen2" onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Screen2')} />
    </View>
  );
}

function Screen2({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, marginTop: 50 }}>
      <Animated.View
        style={{ width: 100, height: 100, backgroundColor: 'green' }}
        sharedTransitionTag="sharedTag"
      />
      <Button title="Screen1" onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Screen1')} />
    </View>
  );
}

export default function SharedElementExample() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{ headerShown: true }}>
        <Stack.Screen name="Screen1" component={Screen1} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Screen2" component={Screen2} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}




package.json

{
  "name": "awesomeproject",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.17",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.26",
    "expo": "~50.0.14",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.11.1",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.73.6",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.30.1",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~3.6.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0"
  },
  "private": true
}


I want my  with a green background color to increase and decrease in height smoothly. Any help would be appreciated.
